# Extending a class that may not be in classpath

Tags: java

I have a class that extends from a package class that may or may not be in the classpath when the program is ran, it isn't called unless the dependency is met,
however it seems to annoy the java verifier that throws a NoClassDefFoundError on attempting to load the program,

Any way around this?

Comment: What about writing your own ClassLoader?

Comment: what do you mean "java verifier"? You're not supposed to get `NoClassDefFoundError" unless you try to load it.

Comment: "it isn't called unless the dependency is met". It seems it is. The class won't be loaded until you use it. From the stacktrace you should be able to determine how you tried to use it.

Comment: Once you extend the class, the base class should be available in the classpath. Why can't you try composition and load using classloader. In that case you will have the freedom to catch ClassNotFoundException

Comment: this is called if the dependency is met, yet the dependency isn't met  worldEdit.getWorldEdit().setEditSessionFactory(new WorldEdit_EditSessionFactoryHandler()); which extends the class

Comment: @clienthax I think you should post the exception and the class (at least partially) from which the exception occurs. That would be the class that accidentally loads the extending class.

Comment: Why not simply add the superclass to the path.  Or don't load the subclass if its superclass isn't there.  There is no way to load (and successfully verify) a class if all of the other classes it references cannot be loaded.

Comment: *"What about writing your own ClassLoader?"* - In effect, that puts the class on the classpath ... and the question is moot.   But of course, this is the only real solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Any way around this?

In practice, no.   The superclass has to be available on the classpath for the loading, linking and verification of the subclass to succeed.  That has to happen before the class can be initialized, and instances of it created.

---

If you can't be sure that the superclass is going to be available, you need to remove all direct and indirect static dependencies on the subclass(es), and then load the subclasses dynamically using `Class.forName()`.  That will fail if the superclass is "missing", but you will get a different exception (not an `Error`) and there is the possibility that your application can continue, if it is designed to cope with the missing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks such as Spring which have "optionally used" code depending on other libraries, use a "Strategy pattern" to put that dependency-specific code into an "inner class" or into a separate class.

The outer class can be loaded & run fine;  it's only when you try & *instantiate* the inner class that the NoClassDefFoundError will be thrown.

So the outer class typically tries (try-catch) instantiating one strategy to use, and then if that fails instantiates a fallback strategy.

```
public class MyService {
    protected MyStrategy strategy;

    // constructor;
    //    -- choose our strategy.
    public MyService() {
        try {
            this.strategy = new ExternalLib_Strategy();
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError x) {
            // external library not available.
            this.strategy = new Standard_Strategy ();
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------

    protected interface MyStrategy {
        public void doSomething();
    }

    protected static class ExternalLib_Strategy implements MyStrategy {
        ExternalLib lib = org.thirdparty.ExternalLib.getInstance();   // linkage may
        public void doSomething() {
            // ... use the library for additional functionality.
        }
    }

    protected static class Standard_Strategy {
        public void doSomething() {
            // ... basic/ fallback functionality.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around to this problem, If your class (subclass) is available in the classpath, you can check whether the parent class is available in the classpath by loading the class file as a resource using the method `ClassLoader.getResource()`. This method will never throw a class not found exception. But this will return null if the class is not found. You can aviod using your class if the resource is null.

See this sample code below:

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object instance = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com/test/package/Base.class");
    Derived derived = null;
    if(instance !=null) {
        derived = new Derived();
        System.out.println(derived.getString()); // call the getString method in base class
    }
    else {
        // The class is not available. But no Exception
                 System.out.println("No Hope"); 

    }

}
```

}